# Animating frame change of UIView is not smooth, results in a bouncy effect

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, frame

I am trying to animate the frame change of an UIView where both the origin and the size changes. The animation doesn't look smooth and has got a bouncy effect. I am using the following code to do that

```
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:0.5
    animations:^{
        self.view.frame = newFrame;
    }];
```

It seems that the size first changes very fast and then the origin changes with the specified duration of the animation which finally results in a bouncy effect. How do I make this look smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On animating the frame change of each of the subviews individually did the magic. Now it animates very smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You could try to change the animation curve, maybe try the linear one.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
});
```

Comment: I had already tried using UIViewAnimationCurveLinear but it didn't work. The size is changed immediately and then the animation for the position change kicks in.

Comment: have you tried using the entire block of code? I just tried it - and both the size and origin animates smoothly at the same time

Comment: Got it right now. I had to animate all the subviews individually else it has got this bounce effect. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't change the size of the the self.view. It only moves it.